# Difference between "[context save:&error]" and "[appDelegate saveContext]"

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, core-data

I am currently writing an app that is using Core Data and reading up on it in Apple's documentation. I realize that when I created a window-based app in Xcode 4 it automatically added an instance method:

```
-(void)saveContext;
```

But in the examples "around town" (most tutorials) I always see people using:

```
[context save:&error];
```

What are the different cases for using one over the other?

Answer (score 3):

- that isn't a class method, it is an instance method
- `[context save:&error]` let's you check for an error and handle it explicitly
- there better be an `if()` around that call to `save:` (i.e. don't just check `error`)
- presumably, `saveContext` is intended to be a higher level operation that handles/presents the error internally.  It probably calls `save:`.

Comment: instance method...totally flunked that one, you're right :) ...yes `save:` is surrounded by an if-statement. And yes internally `saveContext:` does use `save:` but without the error message being handy.But it does print out the error like so: `NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);`

Comment: Thanks for the great tips, I left some things out. But I rather want to know more about the _difference_ between the two ways.